# Android kotlin Webview Splash Screen with 2 Theme

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Sorry for my bad English
I have an Android Kotlin Webview project splash screen with two theme
my project is working fine But I need To Splash Screen wait to Website Load Completely And The Hide
Here is My project codes:
**MainActivity.kt :**

```
    class MainActivity : Activity() {
    private var mWebView: WebView? = null

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_Splash_kotlin_)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview)
        val webSettings = mWebView?.getSettings()
        if (webSettings != null) {
            webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        }

        mWebView?.setWebViewClient(MyWebViewClient())

        // REMOTE RESOURCE
        mWebView?.loadUrl("https://fa.azdamghest.com/")

        // LOCAL RESOURCE
        // mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView!!.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView!!.goBack()
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

**MyWebViewClient.java :**

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        String hostname;

        // YOUR HOSTNAME
        hostname = "fa.azdamghest.com";

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        if (url.startsWith("file:") || uri.getHost() != null && uri.getHost().endsWith(hostname)) {
            return false;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**themes.xml :**

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Splash_kotlin_" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
    
    <style name="splashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_image</item>

        
    </style>
    
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.splash_kotlin_">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Thank you Very much**

Answer (score 0):

Set the visiblity to invisible:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Then put this underneath `mWebView?.setWebViewClient(MyWebViewClient())`:

```
mWebView.webViewClient = object: WebViewClient() {
   var hasWebViewFinishedLoading: Boolean = false
   override fun onPageFinished(viewEl: WebView?, urlStr: String) {
      super.onPageFinished(viewEl, urlStr)
      if (mWebView.progress >= 100 && !hasWebViewFinishedLoading) {
          // Page finished loading.
          hasWebViewFinishedLoading = true
          // Hide the launch screen.
          yourSplashScreenEl.visibility = INVISIBLE
        
          // Show the webView.
          mWebView.visibility = VISIBLE
      }
   }
}
```

So when the page finishes loading for the first time, it hides the splash screen.